# responsive table with rowspan and colspan

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make this table responsive for mobile but could done properly. I tried bootstrap table-responsive class but its not working. because of rowspan i am facing problem so can any suggest me css for this Table

Desktop Format:
https://postimg.org/image/gxj2riueh/

Mobile Format:
https://postimg.org/image/mtq57pwcn/

**Code:**

```
 <table>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td style="background: #fcfbcd;" rowspan="5"
              <p style="text-align: center;">BREAKFAST</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p><strong>MONDAY</strong></p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p><strong>TUESDAY</strong></p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p><strong>WEDNESDAY</strong></p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p><strong>THURSDAY</strong></p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p><strong>FRIDAY</strong></p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p>Milk</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Milk</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Milk</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Milk</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Milk</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p>Kix Cereal</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Whole Grain Raisin</p>
              <p>Bread (1 slice&nbsp; plain, Butter or Marg)</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Cinnamon Raisin Bagel Cream Cheese</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Bran Flakes Cereal</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Cheerios Cereal</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td style="background: #dbc0af;" rowspan="5"
              <p style="text-align: center;">LUNCH</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Juice</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Juice</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Juice</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Juice</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Juice</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p>Chicken Fingers</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Corndog</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Cold cut turkey sandwich</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Hamburger/ Cheeseburger</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Pizza</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p>Green Beans</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Pickle</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p>Mashed Potatoes</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp; Chips</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Brownie</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Fries</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Breadsticks</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td style="background: #e7e5e6;" rowspan="5"
              <p style="text-align: center;">SNACK</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p>Milk /Juice</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Milk /Juice</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Soynut Butter</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Cottage Cheese</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Yogurt <strong><em>4 oz cup</em></strong></p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Celery Sticks</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p>pretzel</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Oreo cookies</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Raisins</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Pears</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>Fruit Cocktail</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Changed the `<td>` "headers" into real table headers `<th>`
- Fixed malformed `<th>` Each of them were missing an angle bracket `>`
- Loaded Bootstrap CSS
- Wrapped the whole `<table>` into a `<section>` and added `.table-responsive`
- Added `.table` and `,table-compact` to `<table>`

```html
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<section class='table-responsive' style='margin:15px auto;'>
  <table class='table table-condensed'>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="background: #fcfbcd;" rowspan="5">
          <p style="text-align: center;">BREAKFAST</p>
        </th>
        <td>
          <p><strong>MONDAY</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><strong>TUESDAY</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><strong>WEDNESDAY</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><strong>THURSDAY</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><strong>FRIDAY</strong></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Milk</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Milk</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Milk</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Milk</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Milk</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Kix Cereal</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Whole Grain Raisin</p>
          <p>Bread (1 slice&nbsp; plain, Butter or Marg)</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Cinnamon Raisin Bagel Cream Cheese</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Bran Flakes Cereal</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Cheerios Cereal</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="background: #dbc0af;" rowspan="5">
          <p style="text-align: center;">LUNCH</p>
        </th>
        <td>
          <p>Juice</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Juice</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Juice</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Juice</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Juice</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Chicken Fingers</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Corndog</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Cold cut turkey sandwich</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Hamburger/ Cheeseburger</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Pizza</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Green Beans</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Pickle</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Mashed Potatoes</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp; Chips</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Brownie</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Fries</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Breadsticks</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="background: #e7e5e6;" rowspan="5">
          <p style="text-align: center;">SNACK</p>
        </th>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Milk /Juice</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Milk /Juice</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Soynut Butter</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Cottage Cheese</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Yogurt <strong><em>4 oz cup</em></strong></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Celery Sticks</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>pretzel</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Oreo cookies</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Raisins</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Pears</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Fruit Cocktail</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

Comment: @zer000ne your solution was super helpful for me. Thank you very much for this. One thing. Can we move the rowspan title to upper row when we see the table on mobile? for eg: BREAKFAST should be served as first row with yellow background then below that DAY row. So additional space reserved for the left side will be saved.

Comment: Hi @PrageethLiyanage we'd be happy to help you, but you'll need to post a question (preferably as a [mcve]). You can refer back to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43034809/2813224) and/or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43035455/2813224). When it's ready, you can leave a comment addressed to me if you'd like, good luck 

Comment: thank you very much mr fo your comment. Please check the question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76487021/how-to-move-rowspan-column-to-top-of-the-row-at-mobile-screens