# How to move rowspan column to top of the row at mobile screens?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have the following table.

[image]

Now at mobile screens I want to move basic column to top to fit everything to single screen. Becuase it saves left side space.like below

[image]

How to do this?

Current Code is below

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

td.spec {
    font-weight: bold;
}

td.value {
    font-weight: normal;
}

td.spec {
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

td.value {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.i-text {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    color: #6a6565 !important;
}

.table-fix-width {
    width: 250px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th.group-heading {
    text-align: center !important;
    background-color: #5a5a5a !important;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<section class="table-responsive">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                <div class="ui-widget text-left">
                    <i class="i-text">Enter model name or part of it</i><br />
                    <input type="text" id="search" />
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <i class="i-text">Enter model name or part of it</i><br />
                    <input type="text" id="search2" />
                </div>
               
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="header" rowspan="4">BASIC</th>
                <td class="spec">Capacity</td>
                <td data-label="" class="value">20GB</td>
                <td data-label="" class="value">20GB</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td class="spec">Name</td>
                <td data-label="" class="value">Product 1</td>
  <td data-label="" class="value">Product 2</td>
            </tr>
                         <tr>
                <td class="spec">Category</td>
                <td data-label="" class="value">TV</td>
         <td data-label="" class="value">TV2</td>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
</section>
```

How to do this?

Comment: While this would be easier to do with CSS grid, you would lose the semantics of a table so I wouldn’t recommend changing  that. However, are you able to change the HTML if necessary?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, I own the site. I can do.. What you propose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I did a quick search and it turns out that we cannot manipulate `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes through css.
Even though the solution below works for your use-case, I'd recommend that you perhaps rethink this layout approach. Using tables for layout purposes is an ancient practice and very troublesome. Maybe you can achieve your goals using something like flexbox or grid. Cheers!

html change:

```
<section class="table-responsive">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='extra--col'></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                <div class="ui-widget text-left">
                    <i class="i-text">Enter model name or part of it</i><br />
                    <input type="text" id="search" />
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <i class="i-text">Enter model name or part of it</i><br />
                    <input type="text" id="search2" />
                </div>
               
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                <th class="header header--desktop" rowspan='4'>BASIC</th>
                <th class="header header--mobile" colspan='4'>BASIC</th>
              </tr>
            <tr>
<!--                 <th class="header" rowspan="4">BASIC</th> -->
                <td class="spec">Capacity</td>
                <td data-label="" class="value">20GB</td>
                <td data-label="" class="value">20GB</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td class="spec">Name</td>
                <td data-label="" class="value">Product 1</td>
               <td data-label="" class="value">Product 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="spec">Category</td>
              <td data-label="" class="value">TV</td>
              <td data-label="" class="value">TV2</td>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
</section>
```

css :

```
/* new styles */

.header--mobile{
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .header--mobile{
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .header--desktop,
  .extra--col{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Update: I have made the edits based on the change.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. Seems your code is working. But the Capacity column is not in order. But the fault is mine. I am really sorry when I paste my code I forgot to put the  <head> part of the table. So I updated the original post, can you please check again? Really sorry. Run the code snippet again.

Comment: @PrageethLiyanage you can check it now :)

Comment: Hi, table is indeed old fashioned if it’s used just for layout, though many email systems still require it. But table has a proper, semantic, meaning and the data given here is tabular so I would not recommend getting rid of that meaning by replacing it with grid. Remember accessibility too.

Comment: @AHaworth fair points, thanks

Comment: @NashitShayan thank you very much, Its works like a charm. Can you please explain the comment of AHaworth. Why did you say fair points? Seems both of you are expert at this :) grid, table arent these same? Again thank you very much

Comment: @PrageethLiyanage You're welcome :) Are you familiar with html elements having semanitc meanings and accessibility ? For eg: A simple div is semantically different from a section, it will be interpreted differently by things like screen-readers. Using a table where we are dealing with actual tabular data is better for those reasons. 
For eg: You can use an h1 for a heading and the accessibility device will consider it a heading, but if you add the same heading in a div, it will not be able to do that.